# How to invoke animation when redirection in jsf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

I have `page1.xhtml` I want to be redirected to `page2.xhtml` after clicking on a button. My aim is to implement an animation after clicking on the button and before the page2.xhtml be displayed.

How can I implement/ invoke those type of animation on redirection ( from bean / from javascript) or How?

Comment: Please improve your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195913/how-to-animate-the-login-process-after-clicking-on-login-button-in-jsf-applicati) instead of asking the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really related to JSF - it's more a HTML and Javascript question. Whenever you do a real navigation, there is no way you can do an animation. So what you have to do is, do make a JSF container (i.e. a panelGroup) and swap the content (the included page). Once you swapped the container's content, you simply do a pushState to update the displayed URL in the browser.